# Dual representation of finite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

If $V$ is a $\mathbb{C}G$ module, then $V^*$ is the dual module with the action
$$(gf)(v) = f(g^{-1}v) $$
for $g\in G,f\in V^*$ and $v\in V$. Where $V^* = \text{Hom}(V,\mathbb{C})$.

What I don't understand is why do we need the inverse of $g$ in $f(g^{-1}v)$, how does this agree with the definition of representation?

Comment: If you find the answer provided to your question useful, make sure you accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, one of the axioms for the group action is $g(hx)=(gh)x$. So let's assume that we've defined our group action on $V^*$ by $(gf)(v):=f(gv)$. Now take two elements $g,h\in G$ and calculate:

$$((gh)f)(v)=f(ghv)$$
$$(g(hf))(v)=(hf)(gv)=f(hgv)$$

These are not necessarily equal when $G$ is nonabelian! And so our "group action" is not an action at all.

But they become equal (regardless of $G$) if we use $(gf)(v):=f(g^{-1}v)$ instead:

$$((gh)f)(v)=f((gh)^{-1}v)=f(h^{-1}g^{-1}v)$$
$$(g(hf))(v)=(hf)(g^{-1}v)=f(h^{-1}g^{-1}v)$$

The same works if we replace $(\cdot)^{-1}$ with any other anti-homomorphism $G\to G$.